# Python Надо получить ключи словаря как названия переменных для последующего расчета

Tags: python

Ребята, если упрощенно - есть словарь вида
d = {'x': 2, 'y': 7}
значения переменных 'x', 'y' вычисляются динамически и названия переменных могут быть любыми.
Поэтому заношу в словарь.
И текстом есть формула:
R = x * y
Мне надо как то получить R
Формула тоже может быть любая, получаю из базы в виде полей:
data[0] - 'R' - имя переменной
data[1] - 'x * y' - формула

Comment: насколько любая может быть формула? Если только две переменных и одно из арифметических действий, то относительно просто. Если интегралы и прочие логарифмы, то сложнее.

Comment: простые действия, может быть (x+y)/z либо a+b+c-d

Answer (score 0):

ну можно так например:

```
myvars = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}

for k, v in myvars.items():
    globals()[k] = v

print(x + y)
```

Comment: Вряд ли так можно. И переменные могут называться иначе, и формула может быть другая. Т.е. можно, но только для этого конкретного случая.

Comment: ну так вроде это и спрашивалось или я что-то не то понял?

Comment: да, количество и название переменных неизвестно, получаю из базы как и саму формулу

Comment: Короче решил так: элементы формулы (операторы, операнды, скобки) записал через пробелы. Распарсил в массив. В массиве заменил переменные на значения из словаря. Из массива сформировал строку обратно (было 'x * y' стало '2 * 7') и потом вычиcлил через функцию обратной польской записи. Результат записал в тот же словарь новой строкой. d = {'x': 2, 'y': 7, 'R': 14}. Получилось красиво.